# Check for NaN in nunjucks template?

Tags: nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I'm trying to display 'n/a' instead of NaN in a popup. Something like:

```
    {% if value == NaN %} 
        n/a
    {% endif %}
```

I realize I can always catch it earlier on before the template is rendered but 
**Is there was a way to check for NaN values in the template?**

Comment: I suspect the NaN value may be rendered by the template itself from a null and/or undefined value but a conditional checking for null doesn't catch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic for a custom filter since there is not a built in filter to check for NaN:

```
nunjucks.configure().addFilter('nan', function(num) {
     if (isNaN(num)){
        return 'n/a';
     }
     return num;
});
```

Then the usage is the same as for any filter:

```
{{ num | nan }}
```